# ReactJS How to pass iterated values to child component from parent component using Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-context

How can I pass values to the looped child component through parent component using Context API instead of passing props.

Parent Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component'
import parentContext from './ParentContext'

export function ParentComponent(props) {
const [ parentState ] = useState([
  {
    "name": "Jonny",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "Raj",
    "age": "24"
  },
  {
    "name": "Rahul",
    "age": "21"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jenny",
    "age": "26"
  }
])
return (
<parentContext.Provider value={{parentState: parentState}}>
{parentState.map((obj, index) => 
<ChildComponent
        name={obj.name}  
        index={index}
        age={obj.age}
    />
)}
</parentContext.Provider>
)
}
```

Child Component

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import parentContext from './ParentContext'

export function ChildComponent(props) {
const parentData = useContext(parentContext)
const [ childState, setChildState ] = useState(parentData)
return (
<div className='container'>
<span>Name: {childState.name}</span>
<span>Age: {childState.age}</span>
</div>
)
}
```

I wanted to pass the values from the Parent Component and send it to Child Component followed by displaying the values within child component. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: You really don't need `context` in this case. What you already have is just fine. There's nothing wrong with passing props from parent to a direct child.

Comment: Also in your child component, you don't need to store the context's value in the state. Note that `childState` or `parentData` will be an array. So `parentData[0]` etc will be each element.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use `context` for above purpose, just change your components to this:

`Parent`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ChildComponent } from "./child-component";

export function ParentComponent(props) {
  const [parentState] = useState([
    {
      name: "Jonny",
      age: "20",
    },
    {
      name: "Raj",
      age: "24",
    },
    {
      name: "Rahul",
      age: "21",
    },
    {
      name: "Jenny",
      age: "26",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      {parentState.map((obj, index) => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={index}
          name={obj.name}
          index={index}
          age={obj.age}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

`Children`:

```
import React from "react";

export function ChildComponent({ name, age }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <span>Name: {name}</span>
      <span>Age: {age}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and if the `parentState` is not going to change it's better just to use a normal variable for that like this:

```
const parentState = [
    {
      name: "Jonny",
      age: "20",
    },
    {
      name: "Raj",
      age: "24",
    },
    {
      name: "Rahul",
      age: "21",
    },
    {
      name: "Jenny",
      age: "26",
    },
  ]
```